# Promise cancel retry bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, cancellation

I have parent function which return Promise. In parent function I'm using [bluebird-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird-retry) package to execute another (nested) promise which just for development purposes currently always reject.

So I'm calling function `parent` which execute 4 times `child`. Parent function code is:

```
const parent = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject, onCancel) => {
        setTimeout(async() => {
            console.log('CALLED PARENT');
            try {
                await retry(child, { max_tries: 4, interval: 500 })
            } catch (e) {
                reject(new Error('Rejected from parent function'));
            }
        },100);

        onCancel(() => {
            console.log('Registered cancel in parent function');
            retry.StopError(new Error('Stop retrying child'));
            reject(new Error('Cancelled parent'));
        });
    });
};
```

So if `child()` always reject it would try 4 times and after 2100ms (100ms timeout and 4 x 500ms interval) would reject error.

However after 2000ms I'm calling bluebird `.cancel` method on promise returned from parent function.

Inside above parent function I have onCancel which suppose to **stop retrying** and reject error. However this does not work as expected because it doesn't stop retrying. Output of [my code](https://gist.github.com/BorysTyminski/f8bc114c5bef248493c037d06ad3b476) is:

> CALLED PARENT
>
> CALLED CHILD
>
> CALLED CHILD
>
> CALLED CHILD
>
> Registered cancel in parent function
>
> Emit stop::all event
>
> Caught stop::all event
>
> CALLED CHILD

but it suppose to be without last 'CALLED CHILD'.

Comment: Don't pass `async function`s around as callbacks, especially not to `setTimeout`! (Use `Promise.delay` instead). You're never calling `resolve` - this can't work. You should avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) altogether.

Comment: I want to stop retrying when `.cancel` method  and `onCancel` function is called.